# How to choose only first "if" to set marker visible true in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a code to filtering marker to show in map

```
if(marker.session == session || session.length === 0) {
               if (marker.category == str || $("#type").length === 0){
                   marker.setVisible(true); 

                   console.log("log2sessionbasedonfilter1"+session);
               }
           }
```

I just want to make this code work if I only use first "if" function and make marker visible.

How to take only one "if" function from that function.

please help me, I just started learning.

Thanks in advance.

-kraken.

Comment: Use the `&&` operator: `if ( (condition) && (condition) )`

Comment: i mean maybe i just want the function "if(marker.session == session || session.length === 0) {" work and can set marker visible true

Comment: You mean like using random boolean flag? That's how one can translate "maybe" into code.

Comment: this my full code 

if ( (marker.session == session || session.length === 0) && (marker.category == str || $("#type").length === 0)){
                   marker.setVisible(true); 
                   
           } else if(marker.session === session || session.length === 0) {
               
               marker.setVisible(true); 
           
       } else {
               marker.setVisible(false);
               infowindow.close(map, marker1);
           }
       }

i want my else if code work

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the whole code so I won't take risks changing it too much..

Take the second if statement and merge it with the first like this:

```
if((/*1st if*/) && (/*2nd if*/)) {}
```

This is REALLY simple..I recommend Eloquent JavaScript by Marijn Haverbeck(sorry if I misspelled) for learning